# How to replace a string/phrase in a text file in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, file-io, string-matching

How would one replace every instance of a given string in a text file in a simple C program ?

One would think this is a question easily Googled, yes ?

At the time of asking,[SanFoundry](https://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-search-replace-word/), [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c-program-to-replace-a-word-in-a-text-by-another-given-word), [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-to-find-and-replace-a-word-in-a-file-by-another-given-word/), [w3resource](https://www.w3resource.com/c-programming-exercises/file-handling/c-file-handling-exercise-9.php), [Codeforwin](https://codeforwin.org/2018/02/c-program-find-and-replace-a-word-in-file.html), [a blog](http://see-programming.blogspot.com/2013/07/c-program-to-replace-word-in-file.html), [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-replace-word-text-another-given-word/) **(twice)** and even [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/163403/c-program-to-find-and-replace-a-word-in-a-file) have badly broken posts that will likely give dysfunctional code to desperate people on deadlines. These are unacceptably bad answers, except maybe the C.R. SE, which addresses its limitations clearly.

This had to thus be addressed in Q&A format on a reliable platform, like Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [initial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63549498/13863346) replaces 'phrases' or 'strings' in the most technical and strict meaning of the words. However, as disclaimed, it will also replace the target where it is *a part of* another string/word/phrase - for instance, '*the*' in '*them*'.

If you want to replace "Bob" in "Bob's", that is the one to go for. However, unless used with care, it can be **too powerful** and destructive.

This answer replaces 'words' (word = string of ASCII characters of decimal value 32 to 126, terminated by any white space character). I.e,Only the *word* 'is' is changed, not the 'is' inside 'This'.

**Algorithm/Steps :**

**0.** , **1.** & **2.** same as in first answer.

**3.** **Infinite Loop :**

i) Get a character from file.

ii) If character == EOF, break the loop.

iii) Else if character is white space character, directly write it to tmp file.

iv) Else take the word, and put it to a buffer. Using `strcmp()`, compare buffer and target.

v) If word is the same, use `strcpy()` to move replacement to buffer.

vi) Write buffer to file.

**4.** and **5.** same as 9. and 10. of original answer.

**Code :**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #define MAX_W 501
    #define MAX_F 261
    
    void eat(void); //clears stdin
    
    int main(){
        printf("\nKeep a backup of your file in case of undesirable effects.\n");
        char frep[MAX_F]; printf("\n Filename : "); scanf("%260[^\n]",frep);eat(); // stores fname in frep[], clears stdin
        FILE * rep = fopen(frep,"r");FILE * tmp = fopen("Temp.Ctt","w");// opens file for reading and tmp for writing
        if(rep==NULL||tmp==NULL){
            // if files could not be opened
            perror("\nError ");
        }
        else{
            char target[MAX_W]; printf("\n Target : "); scanf("%500s",target);eat(); // gets target word
            char replace[MAX_W]; printf("\n Replacement : "); scanf("%500[^\n]",replace);eat();// gets its replacement
            while(1){
                int ch = fgetc(rep);
                if(ch==EOF)
                    break;
                else if(ch==' '||ch=='\t'||ch=='\n'||ch == '\r')
                    fputc(ch,tmp);// directly write whitespace chars
                else{
                    char buffer[MAX_W];
                    fseek(rep,-1,SEEK_CUR);
                    // move FILE pointer 1 byte back to read entire word, not from 2nd char onwards
                    fscanf(rep,"%500s",buffer);
                    if(strcmp(buffer,target)==0)
                        strcpy(buffer,replace);
                    fprintf(tmp,"%s",buffer);
                }
            }
            fclose(rep); int chk =fclose(tmp);
        if(chk==EOF){
            remove("Temp.Ctt"); perror("\nFailed ");
        }
        else{
            if(rename("Temp.Ctt",frep)==0)
                printf("\nSucess.\n\nReplaced any instances of \"%s\" with \"%s\".\n",target,replace);
            else{
                remove(frep);
                if(rename("Temp.Ctt",frep)==0)
                    printf("\nSucess.\n\nReplaced any instances of \"%s\" with \"%s\".\n",target,replace);
                else{
                    remove("Temp.Ctt"); perror("\nFailed ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void eat()
{
    int eat;while ((eat = getchar()) != '\n' && eat != EOF);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This Q&A was made to save future C beginners/intermediates from the nonsense that comes up when searching how to do this.

If you are a beginner, read the algorithm and try implementing it yourself rather than just copying the code.

**Disclaimer :** This algorithm **will** replace `sand` in `sandwich`.  My [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63559398/13863346) mitigates this, if this is an *undesirable effect* (depending on your circumstance).

**Algorithm/Steps :**

0. **Remind user to backup their file.**
1. **Get fileame**.
2. **Initialise** :  Open file entered by user for reading, Open temp file for writing, test for any errors in these file openings.If successful, get the target string and its replacement.
3. **Parse** : Go through the file and record the number of lines in it, then `rewind()` the fptr.
4. **Loop 1**: Staying within the number of lines, get one line from the file.
5. **If**: Using `strstr()`, determine if line contains target string. If yes , then begin Loop 2.
6. **Loop 2**: While any instances of target string are found in line, write to tmp `a)` all characters of line till last match, and `b)` the word to replace. Move the reference of last match to location of current match + length of target string.
7. **Before next line**: Once one iteration of Loop 2 is finished, write any/all characters from last match till `EOL`. Move to next iteration of Loop 1.
8. **Else**: If at `5`, it is found that line contains no instance of target string, write it to file directly.
9. **Cleanup**: `fclose()` tmp and original file.Check if `fclose(tmp)` was successful- if not, throw an error and remove temp file, and finish(since this likely indicates that tmp was not written to as expected, for example if disk became full). Else `rename()` tmp file to filename of original, if that fails(as in Windows systems, where file cannot be renamed to already existing filename), `remove()` original and try again, if even that fails, throw an error and give up.
10. **End**: (optional) print a 'success' message to user if nothing failed.

**Code :**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_W 501
#define MAX_L 2001
#define MAX_F 261

void eat(void); //clears stdin

int main(){
    printf("\nKeep a backup of your file in case of undesirable effects.\n");
    char frep[MAX_F]; printf("\n Filename : "); scanf("%260[^\n]",frep);eat();
    // stores fname in frep[], clears stdin
    FILE * rep = fopen(frep,"r");FILE * tmp = fopen("Temp.Ctt","w");
    // opens file for reading and tmp for writing
    if(rep==NULL||tmp==NULL){
        //NULL is returned if fopen fails.
        perror("\nError ");
    }
    else{
        char target[MAX_F]; printf("\n Target : "); scanf("%500[^\n]",target);eat(); // gets target word
        char replace[MAX_F]; printf("\n Replacement : "); scanf("%500[^\n]",replace);eat();// gets its replacement
        long long lncnt=1;
        while(1){ //parsing file to find number of lines.
            int test = fgetc(rep);
            if(test==EOF)
                break;
            else if(test=='\n'||test=='\0')
                lncnt++;
        }
        rewind(rep);
        //brings pointer back to beginning of file
        char line[MAX_L], *p; int i;
        // line buffer, pointer to position of match, counter i; pointer Last Writing Point (initially points to first element of line[] )
        for(i=1;i<lncnt;i++){
            //while within no. of lines in file
            fgets(line,MAX_L,rep);char * LWP = &line[0];
            //takes line from file 'rep' and stores in line[]
            while((p=strstr(LWP,target))!=NULL){
                // while any matches exist from last writing point
                int x = p-LWP;
                // no. of chars between Last Writing Point and match.
                fprintf(tmp,"%.*s",x,LWP);//writes all chars between last match and current match
                fputs(replace,tmp);
                LWP = p + strlen(target);
                // moves the LWP forward by length of target, so that it points to next valid character.
            }
            fputs(LWP,tmp);
        }
        fclose(rep); int chk =fclose(tmp);
        if(chk==EOF){
            remove("Temp.Ctt"); perror("\nFailed ");
        }
        else{
            if(rename("Temp.Ctt",frep)==0)
                printf("\nSucess.\n\nReplaced any instances of \"%s\" with \"%s\".\n",target,replace);
            else{
                remove(frep);
                if(rename("Temp.Ctt",frep)==0)
                    printf("\nSucess.\n\nReplaced any instances of \"%s\" with \"%s\".\n",target,replace);
                else{
                    remove("Temp.Ctt"); perror("\nFailed ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void eat()
{
    int eat;while ((eat = getchar()) != '\n' && eat != EOF);
}
```

If any further confusion persists, please comment below.

Comment: Finally, this program cannot replace a string with an embedded newline, the newline, if present, must be at the end.

Comment: @chqrlie by that logic, any filename could be a device  ? but doesn't a relative path imply that `Temp.Ctt` will be a file in the cwd ? For *some architectures* , please give examples, this seems rare. As for eat.. to me, both the function and variable are doing similar things - 'eating' stdin. About not replacing strings with embedded lines-- In a text file,  *a string with an embedded newline* is **2** lines, at least for all practical purposes. Hence, a program should be capable of replacing words in each **line**, and I fail to see where the concepts of *strings with newlines* arises ?

Comment: Regarding strings with embedded newlines, newlines are ordinary values, the OP is asking *How would one replace every instance of a given string in a text file*. A string ca contain newlines, replacing for example `"\n\n"` by `"\n"` should remove empty lines, albeit not all of them. He does not restrict this to *within a line*.

Comment: Regarding the device remark, there is a typo in my comment: The `"temp.Ctt"` might also be **on** a different device, causing `rename()` to fail (for example on POSIX systems). This would be the case if the filename provided by the user has a path that leads to a different file system from that of the current directory.

Comment: @chqrlie the OP is me, and I didn't mean replacing a string in that sense ... should I edit it to make that clear ? Also , for the rename() failing, is there anything that can be done about it sensibly ? I **cannot** delete the old file, since that would mean original data is lost even if rename() becomes unsuccessful.

Comment: Dear OP, I missed that you were answering your own question :) The dilemma about renaming the old file to the new file cannot be fully solved portably... You could  try first `rename` and check for failure, if renaming did not work, try reopening the new file for reading and the old file for writing, if the latter fails, chances are you cannot modify the old file, otherwise copy the new file to the old file with a trivial loop: `int c; while ((c = getc(tmp)) != EOF) { putc(c, rep); }` and finally, if `fclose(rep)` succeeds, remove the temporary file with `remove()`.

Comment: @chqrlie I think the easiest thing and perhaps the most practical is to warn the user and expect them to keep a backup of their file. And in the program, to try renaming first - then,if that fails, just `remove()` the old one and `rename()` the new one to the old one. Copying would require closing, reopening, checking for errors in opening, checking for errors in closing after writing... endless error-checking, instead of just expecting the user to follow common sense even after being reminded... I'll change the code to this `rename()` else `remove()` then `rename()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a filter to perform this replacement on `stdin`, writing the modified data to `stdout`. You would create a modified file and then delete the original file and rename or copy the modified file to the original filename.

Care must be taken to replace the string even if it occurs in very long lines, potentially split by `fgets()`.

If the original file contains null bytes, reading lines with `fgets()` would not work properly either.  Reading one line at a time would not allow for replacing a string that contains embedded newlines either.

Here is a version that uses a buffer and avoids these pitfalls. It takes the target string and an optional replacement string as command line arguments:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buffer[4096];
    size_t len1, len2, pos, nread;
    const char *str1, *str2;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s STRING [REPLACEMENT]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    str1 = argv[1];  // string to search and replace
    len1 = strlen(str1);
    str2 = "";       // default replacement is empty
    len2 = 0;
    if (len1 >= sizeof(buffer)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: STRING too long\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    if (len1 == 0) {      // special case empty string
        len1 = len2 = 1;  // replace 0 byte with itself
    } else
    if (argc > 2) {
        str2 = argv[2];
        len2 = strlen(str2);
    }

    pos = 0;
    while ((nread = fread(buffer + pos, 1, sizeof(buffer) - pos, stdin)) != 0) {
        size_t start = 0, i = 0, end = pos + nread;
        while (i + len1 <= end) {
            if (buffer[i] == *str1 && !memcmp(buffer + i, str1, len1)) {
                fwrite(buffer + start, 1, i - start, stdout);
                fwrite(str2, 1, len2, stdout);
                start = i += len1;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
        fwrite(buffer + start, 1, i - start, stdout);
        memmove(buffer, buffer + i, end - i);
        pos = end - i;
    }
    fwrite(buffer, 1, pos, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hmm.. this seems more memory efficient than putting a line in its own buffer

Comment: @APJo: memory efficiency is similar with this approach and `fgets()`, but this method is more general as it allows any file contents and could easily be modified for any target and replacement data.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read a line from the file into a buffer
2. With strstr(), search for next occurrence of "the string".
3. If found, print/write all bytes up to where "the string" is found

   1. Print/write replacement string.
   2. Skip strlen("the sting") bytes of the buffer, and repeat at 2
4. Print the rest of the buffer.
5. Repeat 1

```
#define LINEBUF_LEN 2001

int replace(FILE *in, FILE *out, const char *str, const char *replace) {

    size_t strl;
    char line[LINEBUF_LEN];

    strl = strlen(str);
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), in)) {
        char *y, *x = line;
        while ((y = strstr(x, str))) {
            fwrite(x, 1, y - x, out);
            fputs(replace, out);
            x = y + strl;
        }
        fputs(x, out);
    }

    return !feof(in);
}
```

Comment: Or better, read entire file into a `mmap`ed buffer of (filesize + 1) with `fread()`, nul-terminate the last character and you can treat the entire contents as a string for manipulation putposes.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that would require an even more arbitrary judgement of how large a file *can* be. At least with lines, it would not be logical to fix string size at 2000 or 3000 characters, but with a file ? IMO, that would create *new limitations*.

Comment: Not really, you determine the file size first with `ftell()` or `stat()`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It would still use more memory !

Comment: My answer posted well before this one follows the same algorithm So, this is **redundant** for 1). Next,                                                                       At best, this is a comment. It does not answer the question well, because the question asks how to do replace a phrase/string **in C** and this answer merely gives a general algorithm with no C specific code except references to `strstr()` and `strlen()` which still do not qualify it to actually answer the question. So, for 2) it is also **not really an answer, and at best a comment**.

Comment: I didn't mean to write the code for you. Instead I wanted to make you think about it for yourself. Your code isn't anyway near the the algorithm I wrote. Yours is extremely tedious. I wanted to point that out for you.
I can't comment. Need 50 reps for that. ;)